# How do I $_REQUEST a single array element using PHP

Tags: php

I have a table that is being written out in PHP, here is one line:

```
echo ("<td><input name=\"size[$i]\" type=\"text\" id=\"size[$i]\" value=\"$size[$i]\"></td>\r\n");
```

Let's say for this example $i=4, when I am using $_REQUEST to retrieve the value of  $size[4], how do I do that?

I think I could use a FOR EACH to get ALL the values of $size but how do I get only this specific value?

Comment: replace `$size[$i]` with `$size[4]`?

Comment: i wouldn't recommend using $_REQUEST, but instead, $_GET, $_POST, or $_COOKIE unless you dont mind the data coming from any of those

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Let's say for this example $i=4, when I am using $_REQUEST to retrieve
>   the value of $size[4], how do I do that?

Like this:

```
echo  $_REQUEST['size']['4'];
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but with '4' instead of 4.  This got what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use $_REQUEST which is an array containing $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE values. You would be much better off requesting the $size[4] with a plain $_GET or $_POST depending on the action of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [PHP $_REQUEST as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543950/php-request-as-array) . I believe they pretty much cover how to get elements from the $_REQUEST-array.