# Is it possible to scope a submit with html/php?

Tags: php, html

I have a form wrapped table with many repeating rows.  The table's purpose is to allow editing of user accounts. Each row look like this:

```
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" name="username" value="$row->username" /></td>";
   <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="$row->fname" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="$row->lname" /></td>
   <td><input type="email" name="email" value="$row->email" /></td>
   <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="edituserbutton" value="$row->id" >Edit</button>";
</tr>
```

I build this table.  I can change the names of each of the input elements, on a row
to row basis, so that they are made unique; `name="username##"` where `## = $row->id`.
But I was wondering if the post could be scoped somehow to the row.  I'm trying 
to avoid having to build keys like this

```
$id = $_POST['edituserbutton'];
$user_name = $_POST['username'.$id];
```

Is this possible?

And also, concerning the presentation and editing of data, is this how it's generally done?

=========== update

Here's what I did.  Works great.  Thank you all:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('button[name=edituserbutton]').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var buttonvalue = $(this).attr("value");
     alert("button value is " + buttonvalue);
      // .. business here

      return;
   })
});
```

Comment: You could do this with Javascript. Make your button an `onclick` event and then walk the DOM to grab all the form elements within that row. Then use AJAX to submit the data. There are plenty of examples of how to do this

Comment: You can have PHP create an array from the input values, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543950/php-request-as-array and http://us.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Comment: What @Machavity said is honestly the best practice. It will provide the most optimal user experience, too.

Comment: I like the jquery idea.  To make it easy I'd just stick a row id in <tr> and take it from there.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" name="username[$row->id]" value="$row->username" /></td>";
   <td><input type="text" name="fname[$row->id]" value="$row->fname" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="lname[$row->id]" value="$row->lname" /></td>
   <td><input type="email" name="email[$row->id]" value="$row->email" /></td>
   <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="edituserbutton" value="$row->id">Edit</button>";
</tr>
```

Then, in PHP

```
$id = $_POST['edituserbutton'];
$newUserName = $_POST['username'][$id];
```

If you also want to avoid submitting a lot of redundant data, you'll want to make each row a form on its own, like

```
<tr>
<form action="...">
   <td><input type="text" name="username" value="$row->username" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="$row->fname" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="lname" value="$row->lname" /></td>
   <td><input type="email" name="email" value="$row->email" /></td>
   <td>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="edituserbutton">Edit</button>
       <input type="hidden" name="rowId" value="$row->id"/>
   </td>
</form>
</tr>
```

Comment: You could make it like this too, this looks very convenient to use to me `$row->id[username]` so the key would be `id` and under the key all the info regarding that id..

Comment: While I give you props for the effort, this answer isn't scalable (you have to submit the whole form and if he's showing 100 rows this would be a LONG parse) and it doesn't actually answer the question (he doesn't want to submit the entire form, just one row)

Comment: @Machavity You're right in that it's not efficient. However, as I read it, the OP did not state that he wanted to *submit* only part of the data. - For that, he'd just make each row its own form.